# Converting Pdf pages into images in nodeJS using pdf2img module

Tags: node.js, pdf

I am trying to convert Pdf pages into images using the pdf2img module.My code is as follows..

```
var pdf2img = require('pdf2img');
var input   = __dirname + '/pd.pdf';
pdf2img.setOptions({
  type: 'png',                      // png or jpeg, default png
  size: 410,                       // default 1024
  density: 200,                    // default 600
  outputdir: __dirname + '/output'  // mandatory, outputdir must be absolute path
});

pdf2img.convert(input, function(info) {
  console.log(info);
});
```

I am getting following error after running above code..

```
C:\node\app>node conv.js

events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: spawn pdfinfo ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1053:32)
    at child_process.js:1144:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[pdf2img](https://github.com/MidEndProject/node-pdf2img/blob/master/package.json#L15) is using pdfinfo for the pdf library.

From pdfinfo's [homepage](https://github.com/ecarter/node-pdfinfo):

**Requires**

```
Node.js
npm node package manager
xpdf / pdfinfo(1)
```

So download and install [Xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html) on your windows computer, and you will hopefully get rid of the `ENOENT` error.

Comment: Thanks...above error is resolved but now i am getting the following error...{ [Error: write EPIPE] code: 'EPIPE', errno: 'EPIPE', syscall: 'write' }

Comment: Maybe post that as a new question? I need more information.